# Aggregate SQL results

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, aggregation

I have a SQL table that looks like this:

```
region    managed    sent        received    result
B01       0          9/4/2023    NULL        587320004
B02       1          7/31/2023   8/12/2023   587320002
B03       1          8/11/2023   9/5/2023    587320002
B04       0          9/1/2023    9/17/2023   587320001
B01       1          9/15/2023   9/16/2023   587320003
B01       0          8/12/2023   NULL        587320001
B02       0          6/28/2023   NULL        587320005
B04       1          7/15/2023   7/30/2023   587320004
B01       0          9/9/2023    9/12/2023   587320002
```

The table actually has few thousands rows.

I want to create a result that would look like this where columns would represent count by region:

```
                                                    B01   B02   B03   B04
# of records sent (managed = 1)
# of records sent last week (managed = 1)
# of records sent (managed = 0)
# of records sent last week (managed = 0)
# of records returned (received is NOT null)
# of records not returned (received is NULL)
# of records (result = 587320001 and managed = 0)
# of records (result = 587320001 and managed = 1)
```

Is it possible to do this all in 1 go instead of possibly creating multiple queries using UNION or CTE's?

I managed to do something like this:

```
select region, managed,
count(case when sent >= @StartLastWeek then 1 else null) as 'Sent Last Week',
count(*) as 'Sent All Time',
count(case when received is not NULL then 1 else null) as 'Received',
count(case when received is NULL then 1 else null) as 'Not Received',
count(case when result = 587320001 then 1 else null) as 'Positive',
count(case when result = 587320002 then 1 else null) as 'Negative'
from mytable
group by region, managed
```

this gives me what I need, but in a different format. It gives me 1 row per region/managed and multiple columns for each count. I want the counts to be rows and regions to be columns.

Thanks.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: We use MS SQL server.

Comment: Posting the desired output would be ideal. I'm not understanding what you are after here.

Comment: @ChrisAlbert I did post it (2nd block of my post shows the desired output).

Comment: PIVOT the results from your query. And ideally do that in your application software, because they are much better at solving this kind of problem. There is no easy way to do it in SQL. (or it might be unpivot - I get them mixed up).

Comment: General note: You can remove the `ELSE` clause of your conditional counts, they don't have any effect.

Comment: SQL is the worst tool to do this, make your live easier and do this in your application software where this is easy in stead of fighting with a language where this is very very hard

Comment: A Matrix in SSRS or a Pivot Table in Excel would be much better way to achieve your goal, for example.

Comment: SQL is not a pretty report generator. Columns represent the *definitions* of data, rows represent the actual data. So data does not belong in column headers. Your current query is the way it should be. Do any pivoting/transposing in a reporting tool. You could in theory take out `managed` from the grouping, and instead put it into the columns (so doubling up the columns for 0 and 1)

Comment: I've finally managed to achieve what I needed. Had to use UNPIVOT and then PIVOT to get the right result. Thanks all who helped!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard-coded, but you can try this:

```
declare @StartLastWeek datetime=getdate();
 
WITH Counts AS (
    SELECT
        region,
        SUM(CASE WHEN managed = 1 AND [sent] >= @StartLastWeek THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SentLastWeek_Managed1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN managed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SentAllTime_Managed1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN managed = 0 AND [sent] >= @StartLastWeek THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SentLastWeek_Managed0,
        SUM(CASE WHEN managed = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SentAllTime_Managed0,
        SUM(CASE WHEN received IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Received,
        SUM(CASE WHEN received IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NotReceived,
        SUM(CASE WHEN result = 587320001 AND managed = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Positive_Managed0,
        SUM(CASE WHEN result = 587320001 AND managed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Positive_Managed1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN result = 587320002 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Negative
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY region
)
SELECT
    'Sent (Managed = 1)' AS Metric,
    region,
    SentAllTime_Managed1 AS Value
FROM Counts
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Sent Last Week (Managed = 1)' AS Metric,
    region,
    SentLastWeek_Managed1 AS Value
FROM Counts
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Sent (Managed = 0)' AS Metric,
    region,
    SentAllTime_Managed0 AS Value
FROM Counts
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Sent Last Week (Managed = 0)' AS Metric,
    region,
    SentLastWeek_Managed0 AS Value
FROM Counts
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Received' AS Metric,
    region,
    Received AS Value
FROM Counts
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Not Received' AS Metric,
    region,
    NotReceived AS Value
FROM Counts
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Positive (Managed = 0)' AS Metric,
    region,
    Positive_Managed0 AS Value
FROM Counts
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Positive (Managed = 1)' AS Metric,
    region,
    Positive_Managed1 AS Value
FROM Counts;
```

The result will be like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Heinz. It looks good. I've managed to do what I needed using a query similar to your CTE and then UNPIVOTing and PIVOTing the results.